# Do you have to look for local extrema at endpoints that are not in the domain?

Tags: real-analysis

I've seen that local extrema can be found at different points, and end points of an interval / domain, is such points.

Now, do we have to look for local extrema in our function if the end point isn't included in the interval. For instance, let's say we have a function $f(x) = \ln(x)$, and we give it an interval of $(1,10)$. Should I then be looking for local extrema at $x=1$ and $x=10$?

Thanks.

Comment: No, you should not. The domain of the function contains all the $x$-values for which the function is defined. So if your domain is $(1,10)$, you don't really know what $f(1)$ is. Even though it might make sense to put $x = 1$ into the expression, you should think that the expression is not valid outside the domain.

Comment: You need to look at least at $f(x)$  as $x \to 1^+$ and $x \to 10^-$ which here have the limits $\ln(1)$ and $\ln(10)$

Comment: Do you just want to know where the local extrema are, or do you want to use that information for something else? If you just want to know where the local extrema are, they cannot be outside the domain, so you do not need to check for the limit as $x$ approaches the end point.